# Binary search tree - why does it not work without the "return" statement

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

When I want to search for a name which is in the tree, without the `return` statement I only get `None` but why?

See code comment `#<----`

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


    def child(self, data):
        if self.data == data:
            return

        if self.data < data:
            if self.right:
                self.right.child(data)
            else:
                self.right = Tree(data)

        elif self.data > data:
            if self.left:
                self.left.child(data)
            else:
                self.left = Tree(data)


    def search(self, elem):
        if self.data == elem:
            return True

        if self.data < elem:
            if self.right:
                return self.right.search(elem) #<----
            else:
                self.right = False

        elif self.data > elem:
            if self.left:
                return self.left.search(elem) #<----
            else:
                self.left = False
```

Comment: If you don't `return` anything, the default return is `None`.

Comment: Because the original call needs to return what the search of the subtree returns.

Comment: I still do not really get it. I mean he will be in `if self.data == elem: return True`. So why does he return `None` and not  `True` wihtout the `return` statement?

Comment: You also should not be replacing empty subtrees with `False`; you should *return* `False`.

Comment: Do you understand how recursion works? Having `self.rigth.search(elem)` return `True` does *not* automatically make the current call to `search` return `True`. You have to be explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Without return, you ignore the result of the subtree search and fall through to the end of the method, at which point you return `None` implicitly.

You also need to return `False` when the appropriate subtree is empty, not set the subtree reference to `False.`

```
def search(self, elem):
    if self.data == elem:
        # Found it!
        return True

    elif self.data < elem:
        # If it exists, it's in the right subtree
        return self.right is not None and self.right.search(elem)
        
    else:
        # If it exists, it's in the left subtree
        return self.left is not None and self.left.search(elem)
```